# Facing challenges in ScriptShape(USP10.dll) Windows API in Windows 10

Tags: c++, gdi, uniscribe

1. Application under Test        : Notepad
2. Contents Typed in the Notepad : ABCD

Behavior observed in Windows environments :-

**Windows 7/Windows 8.1** : In order to draw the text ABCD in notepad, the call gets into ScriptShape Windows API(USP10.dll) to generate Glpyhs, and then moves to ExtTextOut(GDI32.dll).

**Windows 10** : In order to draw the text ABCD in notepad, calls enters into ExtTextOut(GDI32.dll) without going through ScriptShape Windows API(USP10.dll).

If we analyse the process dmp of notepad.exe then in case of Windows 7/Windows 8.1 USP10.dll is invoked whereas in case of Windows 10 the USP10.dll is never invoked, which implies that none of the ScriptShape related calls are getting triggered.  So, my question is in case of Windows 10 where is it getting routed to ? Which dll is involved to generate the Glyph indices from Unicode character if USP10.dll is not involved ?

Any suggestion will help

Comment: now this moved to `gdi32full.dll` but in what question/problem ?

Comment: for example next function called `long GenericEngineDrawGlyphs(IShapingClient *,IShapingFont *,SHAPING_PROPERTIES const *,CShapingString &,CReadonlyShapingVector<unsigned short> &,CReadonlyShapingVector<SHAPING_CHARPROP> &,unsigned short const *,SHAPING_GLYPHPROP const *,long,long const *,long const *,SHAPING_GLYPHOFFSET const *,IShapingDrawingSurface *,void *,long,long);` but are this give you something ?

Comment: this is called inside [`ScriptStringOut`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368571(v=vs.85).aspx) - now this function in `gdi32full.dll`

Comment: The correct answer is UI Automation, not hooking system functions.

Comment: I was able to hook successfully into ScriptStringAnalyse in Windows 10.

Comment: Also, I was able to successfully hook into ScriptStringOut, but still I am not sure why ScriptShape is not getting called on Windows 10 ?